# Interface to collect successful remote backups status

Tags: backup, monitoring

I would like to deploy into our infrastructure a web interface that could register when the copies are finished and if for some reason they haven't.
The current issue is that we are doing on site backups for customers, for each backup a mail is sent ad the end of the backup, the problems is that sometimes the mail isn't sent for a variety of reasons:

- System doesn't have internet
- Backup system crashed before sending the mail
- etc..

What I'd like to do is to have a web interface that the backup software cant visit after doing the backup (either if it's a success or a fail), that acknowledges that the backup has finished, after some time, I'd like to receive a report of the machines that hadn't done the backup.

Is there anything remotely similar to this that I could use/adapt to our environment?

UPDATE: Just found out this ([paessler.com](http://www.paessler.com/knowledgebase/en/topic/47023-how-can-i-monitor-my-backup-software-to-be-sure-backup-succeeded-last-night)) that seems to be a privative solution of what I intended.

Comment: Basically you can wrap your backup commands into a script and then the script can to any action based on exist status, no? Or bacula backup software... it has nice web ui...

Comment: I am using a variety of backup systems, from custom rsync to robocopy or cobian for windows and others. Moreover the backups are done locally (to a external drive), afaik bacula can control only it's own backups, not the status of some other places.

Comment: Then you have to connect it to a monitoring system, try zabbix, it would report your backup status into a dashboard.

Comment: This is so funny. OK, is SMTP under your control? If so, you can do fancy procmail filtering and run specific command (like make a report to monitoring system).

Comment: After you wrote about zabbix, I could find a couple of links on how are using ncsa to check for this, but my initial idea was on the line of creating a postbackup script that did an wget to a url such as backup.example.com/?id=system_id&status=OK, and postprocess this in a web interface. The route you are telling, using procmail/imap is interesting too. If I could found someones project on this I might decide for one route or the other.

Answer (score 2):

Summary: you have various backup solutions and each of them reports backup status via mail. The mail format is not same. Modifying backup scripts could be problematic (testing, approving..), so parsing/exploring already functioning existing mail-based notifications is easier way to go...

If you don't want to spend big money for fancy solutions, open source world offers you at least two solutions:

- if you have IMAP mail, you can use lua-based imap-filter and check and filter your mails and send an alert to your monitoring solution, or to do any action you want (like added a line into a web page).
- or you can use procmail to do it. procmail filtering can execute specific action based on filtering criteria. again it can be connected to your monitoring solution or you can run your own action.

I would go with the 2nd. Some monitoring solutions can monitor a log file, so you can instruct procmail to write a line into a log file which is constantly monitored by monitoring agent. Or you can reformat the mail and feed it into a logstash, as main center of your logging events. Of course procmail would still (if you want, I suppose you still want) to send you original mail.

For not receving a mail at all, you can create a trigger which would check if backup mail was received in last X hours (I suppose you do backups daily). If not, you can create an alert into your monitoring system to inform you that something is wrong on a specific server as it did not send mail about backup status.

Comment: I will send an extra copy to an special inbox (a catchall for all the backups)   so I can delete de email after processing, still, I have to prepare a backend to store all the data an register the events.
That's the part I'd have like to have done :)